# Hovering values and enable links when the user clicks on tree map blocks

Tags: r

I have sample code where I generated a tree map. But there are few drawbacks, there are links in the dataframe. So when the user clicks on specific block, the respective url has to be opened. Here it is google.com

```
library(plotly)

dtd7 <- structure(
  list(
    topic = structure(
      c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L,
        5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L),
      .Label = c("Apple", "Avocado", "Banana", "Carrot", "Mango","Mushroom", "Onion", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Sweet-lemon", "Watermelon", "Wildberry"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    n = structure(
      c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L,
        7L, 8L, 1L),
      .Label = c("23", "24", "36", "42", "43", "46", "48", "52", "56", "61", "82", "94"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    link = structure(c("<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                       "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                       "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                       "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                       "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                       "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                       "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>"))
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-13L)
)

p <- plot_ly(
  dtd7,
  labels = ~ topic,
  parents = NA,
  values = ~ n,
  type = 'treemap',
  hovertemplate = "Ingredient: %{label}<br>Count: %{value}<extra></extra>"
)

p
```

Comment: You're asking for an interactive format, but `treemap` produces a static image, it isn't made to be interactive. I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Edit: Try googling for "r interactive treemap" and you'll find plenty of examples: [1](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/237-interactive-treemap.html), [2](https://plotly.com/r/treemaps/), [3](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/260881_6e05cf8f21e44cbea7fdff082409a63a.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i have edited my question. Just need your help